# scanning and grepping

Tags: centos, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file (`*.ses`) which contains following line

```
$   rea ses '../../../../abcdefgh/abcd_efgh-A20_ABC-abcdefgh-Abcdefgh_Abcdef_123er_vb001.ses'
```

When I use this command:

```
cat a4.ses | grep -im1 'rea ses' | awk -F'[/]' '{print $NF}'
```

the output is:

```
abcd_efgh-A20_ABC-abcdefgh-Abcdefgh_Abcdef_123er_vb001.ses'
```

I just want to output to be:

```
abcd_efgh-A20_ABC-abcdefgh-Abcdefgh_Abcdef_123er_vb001
```

without the extension.

How can I do that?

Comment: I've reverted the damage to this question from an earlier edit. Please note that the single quote on the end of the "faulty" output provided in this question is really there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `.ses'` is a static extension, simply hard-code the removal of those trailing 5 characters into awk by printing the string from the beginning until 5 from the end:

```
awk -F/ '{print substr($NF, 1, length($NF)-5)}'
```

If the length of the extension can vary, then replace it with the empty string before printing it:

```
awk -F/ '{gsub(/\..+$/, "", $NF); print $NF}'
```

Comment: don't want to hardcode any numbers!!

Comment: Thansks for the Tip... I have combined your way in-combination with one of my other programm!! Super working

Comment: I do agree with Hardcoding ( if the extension is same). Thanks

Comment: well-spotted, @roaima; thank you! I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` supports perl compatible regular expression (PCRE) syntax:

```
$ grep -Po 'rea ses.*/\K[^.]*' file
abcd_efgh-A20_ABC-abcdefgh-Abcdefgh_Abcdef_123er_vb001
```

Explanation:

- match `rea ses` and then greedily everything up to `/` inclusive; then
- match the longest sequence of non-period characters
- discard (`\K`) the left portion and output only what remains of the match (`-o`)

Comment: Thanks Steeldriver. will you please explain the pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

You can dispense with that pipeline and use `sed` instead

```
sed -n '/rea ses/s!^.*/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$!\1!p' a4.ses
```

Output

```
abcd_efgh-A20_ABC-abcdefgh-Abcdefgh_Abcdef_123er_vb001
```

What that `sed` command does can be described as follows

1. `-n` do not print anything unless a match is made
2. `/rea ses/` only consider lines that match this RE
3. `s!...!...!p` substitute the RE within the first two exclamation marks (`!`) for the following string, but only print the line if a match occurs
4. The RE `^.*/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$` matches

   - Everything up to the last slash `/`
   - Everything from there to the last dot `.` (remembered as pattern `\1`)
   - Everything else
5. The substitution of the pattern described in #4 is made with pattern `\1`, i.e. your filename without the trailing dotted extension

Comment: can you suggest still simpler way ? length of the last name may vary, it may or may not contain any '_' characters!!

Comment: [`grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405795/100397) if you have a suitable one. Or [`awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405791/100397). Or even `python` if you want. There are lots of solutions. This is mine.

Comment: Thanks Roaima...using your way in combination with my other scripts.

Comment: your response was super fast :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename` to remove a trailing extension:

```
cat a4.ses | grep -im1 'rea ses' | awk -F'[/]' '{print $NF}' | xargs basename -s .ses\'
```

(submitted for completeness, given your process, @steeldriver's answer is better)

Comment: ... or escaped. Fixed. Thx